# Dump the firmware from an STM8 microcontroller

Tags: dump, firmware, stm8

I have a [600W digital step up converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W8TVBGP) with broken STM8S103K3T6C and another that is currently working OK. Is there a way to copy (dump) firmware from the working one and upload it to the new chip. Since I have only one working, I have to be extra careful not to damage the working controller. I do have some basic experience with STM32, but I am grateful for any help I could get. I have a copy of [ST-Link v2 programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RYVLN4U). Apparently (if there is a way), it has to be done via SWIM (which I don't nothing about, started reading few days ago). Not sure what is the proper way to start. Converter itself has UART pins at the right side of the board.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if the chip is not locked, yes it's possible using SWIM interface. use STVP tool to extract firmware from the old one or to program it to the new one. it is bundled in a package called "ST toolset" for STM8 and [downloadable from ST website](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stvp-stm8.html). the SWIM needs 1 pin (plus reset if target uses that pin). despite that the STM8s hvae 3~5V supply, it's better to use 3.3V supply for it for the sake of the other circuitry. you can extract it even when the device is on, so there's no need to connect a supply pin from programmer to it.

Comment: Be aware that removing the read out protection will erase the whole chip